# Non-Localhost PyMongo Client

Tags: python, mongodb

I was wondering if I can make a PyMongo client that is not localhost such that I can retrieve data from external computers. Is this possible? I read the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) but there doesn't anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - just use that external computer hostname or IP address instead of localhost.

For example:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://10.20.30.40/")
```

Another example - I have a MongoDB setup with authentication and multiple nodes in a replica set, so I am using

```
pymongo.MongoClient(
    "mongodb://user:password@host1,host2,host3/dbname?replicaSet=rsname",
    read_preference=pymongo.ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
```

Comment: So how exactly do I obtain such an IP? For example, can I use command prompt to find the IP on one computer and then start storing data from another? Are there any passwords or permission restrictions?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi You can obtain IP address of the computer with command `ip addr` or `ifconfig` on Linux or `ipconfig` on MS Windows.

Comment: So there's no sort of permission restrictions? Does PyMongo actually write a database file on the host such that I would actually be writing a file on this additional computer?

Comment: MongoDB has authentication system with access control. It depends on the configuration whether it's enabled. If it's enabled, you need to sign in first with username and password before you can read or write anything. If authentication is disabled (`noauth = true` in mongodb.conf) everybody can do anything, which is of course not secure. Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/

Comment: @MalikBrahimi PyMongo doesn't write any database files anywhere. It just connects (locally or over a network) to a MongoDB server - this server writes database files...

Comment: Thanks for the help! Lastly I was wondering if there is anyway to public access this host outside of the home network. I want to use my Raspberry Pi as an external host at home such that I can access it from school.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That should be possible, but probably will require some work, because computers in home networks are usually "hidden" from outside. If you have IPv6 then you probably have to enable access from outsite in your router firewall. If you don't have IPv6 (so you have IPv4 only) then you need to setup port forwarning and use http://www.whatsmyip.org/ to see what is the IP address visible from outside. Read more here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85462/what-is-my-computer-ip-address-knowing-that-i-have-a-router

Comment: @MalikBrahimi You will probably want to use a "dynamic DNS" service, because home network IP address can change from time to time: http://duckdns.org/why.jsp

Comment: I know about port forwarding although it is not my router to mess with. I'm still a minor, dang it! Anyway, is there an alternative, perhaps like: `hos.t.i.p@rou.t.e.r`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Use VPN like Hamachi or create a SSH tunnel with connection forwarding from your Pi to a publicly accessible server (you can get a small one on Amazon AWS for free).